# Are contigencies always present in offer letters?

Tags: hiring-process

I would like to know if an offer letter from an employer will always have any mandatory contigencies.  For example, if a background check is required, will it say so on the offer letter?

Comment: My company has contingencies on the letter.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your location.  In some parts of the world an offer letter is just that, an offer.  Well in the US an offer letter is the equivalent to your drunk uncle scribbling something on a piece of paper.  Meaning I wouldn't think much of it other than the salary/location.  It could simply say "comply with company guidelines" which might include a drug test and background check.

In other parts of the world - many countries in Europe and a few in Asia an offer letter is generally a concrete contract.  Then I would say, if it doesn't mention it you are good - but I am over generalizing on the regions here.

Specifically with background checks - a company in the US can really get one whenever they feel like it.  There are lots of companies that take so long to do background and drug tests that they waive these during interviews just to get people in place.  I have heard guys failing a drug test or something coming up on a background check (for some jobs you need to be bonded and can't get insurance with certain things on record) 2-3 months after getting hired.  So no you are really never safe from these things.  If it is your background check it is really two things.  #1 How bad is it?  #2 Is it something that you point blank lied about on resume or during interviews?

If you have something really bad that would come up on a background check and will get fired for sure - I wouldn't tell them and just hope they don't find out - but doing this you might get canned at any time in the future if they find out.

Comment: In the USA, employments are normally considered "at will" meaning you can be fired any time for any reasons.

Comment: @Dan - yes but there are a mountain of laws around giving someone an employment contract and never abiding by it.  Even "at will" notes that there needs to be a reason for letting someone go.  We had a friend a few years ago who quit job because she got an offer from another place in a different city.  She moved with her husband and showed up to work the first day and they told her the job wasn't hers... She got almost 500k after taking them to court for lost wages and moving fees.  Yes it is "at will" but not a freedom to play games.

Comment: That's a little different than what is considered "at will." What happened to your friend is fraud, not "at will" employment. Someone failing a background check on her second day of employment can be terminated. Many times a background check can take a few days or weeks and during that time a person can be employed at said company.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the industry and where you are. Generally speaking a simple background check will be performed (ex credit check, criminal, education, etc). Depending on the background check, they may terminate you even after employment.

Comment: The position is for a project manager at an advertising agency. The location is South Florida (advertising). Should they not disclose that they will be doing a background check on the offer letter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'll be doing a background/drug tests. It's very common and no place I ever been did not have it. The offer letter may or may not contain this but it is sure to be standard on-boarding paperwork.

Comment: I've worked at 7 different ad agencies and they have never done a background check.  But I don't know how new hires work nowadays.